# What is the relationship between subversion and visusal studio.net 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn

I am asking this question since I am new to anksvn. I basically need to checkin code that I wrote in a C# 2010 application into the latest version of anksvn. I have obtained the impression that anksvn is based upon a file directory structure where the solution file is at the highest level and all other folders are at a different directory level.

I have also seen C# apps where the solution file can be the following:
1. The solution file has its project files at a lower level that it is.
2. The solution file has its project files at the same level where the solution file is located.

Thus can you tell me and/or point me to a reference that will verify and/or tell me how the file structure of anksvn is related to visual studio.net 2010?

Comment: `anksvn` is an add-in for Visual Studio that adds subversion support to it. Subversion is a source control management system - that would be what you check in to. How you layout your project files is up to you and has **nothing** to do with subversion or anksvn.

Comment: some solution files I place in anksvn are good and compile clean right after you check them out from subversion. However a few other solutions I check into subversion and check them out do not compile. They are missing references. Thus can you tell me why I get these compile errors?

Comment: Well, you said it - missing references. The dependencies were probably not checked in.

Comment: What do I need to do so that the references are checked into anksvn? Did I miss some step in loading the solution file to anksvn?

Comment: You need to find them, re-add to the projects and check-in.

Comment: I will do what you recommend by readding the references and check the code into anksvn. Now my question is, when I am ready to check this code out again will I need to readd the references again?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, if the references point to the relative location that you checked them into.

Comment: What do you mean by the relative locations? One reference that is needed is for the common.logging.dll. Do you know where I can find this dll?

Comment: It is a third party DLL - it is not part of the .NET base class library. You will need to ask the original developer.

Comment: How do you know that it is a third party dll? How do you check for dlls that are part of the .net framework or base classes?

Comment: The name. It is not a `System.*` DLL, so not part of the BCL.